# I have a few questions about my token

Tags: solidity, pancakeswap, binance-smart-chain, liquidity

Recently I have created a meme token based on the Gotta Lock In meme.

When I deployed it to PancakeSwap, I deposited 19.000.000 $LOCKIN alongside with ~15$ of BNB into the liquidity pool.

However once i click add it seems like the liquidity pool has way less than the amount of BNB I have deposited into, (attached image 1)

I was able to salvage it using the rest of my funds to bring back the exchange rate but the 15$ I deposited seems to have just disappeared.

Another question I want to ask is that on CoinMarketCap the Honeypot flag was raised saying this token cannot be sold. I understand that this is a new token and of course it will be flagged as a Honeypot but I don't understand why it cannot be sold (attached image 2)

Attached images:

Image 1: https://ibb.co/bKxwhT2

Image 2: https://ibb.co/3MYWs8t

Info about my token:

Contract: https://bscscan.com/token/0x8cf02b890caad0770ba25d7da3cb11de275ce527

CMC: https://coinmarketcap.com/dexscan/bsc/0x1c3e2bafcda85d49fa72072d12bf1212bde49fd5/

Swap: https://pancakeswap.finance/swap?outputCurrency=0x8cf02b890caad0770ba25d7da3cb11de275ce527

Comment: Hello and welcome! Instead of images, could you please put links to the transactions in which you have the contract add liquidity? In general, we ask people not to use images to ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I deployed it to PancakeSwap, I deposited 19.000.000 $LOCKIN alongside with ~15$ of BNB into the liquidity pool.

> However once i click add it seems like the liquidity pool has way less than the amount of BNB I have deposited into

You got attacked by a pretty famous bot [c0ffeebabe.eth](https://etherscan.io/address/0xC0ffeEBABE5D496B2DDE509f9fa189C25cF29671) that drained all your WBNB.

Here's your `addLiquidityETH` [transaction](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x05e8b0161e441f9f42afc1f24f407ce6781c4be8d511cfc1eeb967dd27a396cd): note it's in block 34979935 with position 3 in the block.

And here's the bot [transaction](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xcb75c5880da2138633506b2493a3eeb22e7b948e2d5bc129afadbbf1396e0508): it's in block 34979935 (same block) with position 4 in the block. It transfers your WBNB to the bot through the bot contract. Go ahead and inspect the transaction and your contract to deep dive into what exactly happened there.

> Another question I want to ask is that on CoinMarketCap the Honeypot flag was raised saying this token cannot be sold

Honeypot does not necessarily mean the token cannot be sold, it can mean any possibly malicious code (CMC themselves say that in the tooltip).

For example, your token doesn't have the ownership renounced (or even a function to renounce ownership), the `swapAndDistribute` doesn't seem to have checks and is open to everyone. This is all just from a quick glance and is enough to flag your token as Honeypot.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I will try to look into it.

One last question about the swapAndDistribute function, do I make it an onlyOwner function?

Comment: And is there anyway to defend against these types of bots?